# Firebird2.5-super Ubuntu 16.10 где папка include

Tags: linux, qt, firebird

Не могу найти папку include для подключения к проекту Qt. Может я не ту версию устанавливаю?

```
sudo apt-get install firebird2.5-super

dpkg --get-selections | grep firebird
firebird-dev                    install
firebird2.5-classic             deinstall
firebird2.5-common              install
firebird2.5-common-doc              install
firebird2.5-server-common           install
firebird2.5-super               install
libreoffice-sdbc-firebird           install

gbak -z
gbak:gbak version LI-V2.5.6.27020 Firebird 2.5
gbak: ERROR:requires both input and output filenames
gbak:Exiting before completion due to errors

 dpkg -L firebird2.5-super
/.
/etc
/etc/init.d
/etc/init.d/firebird2.5-super
/usr
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/fbstat
/usr/bin/fbsvcmgr
/usr/bin/fbtracemgr
/usr/bin/gbak
/usr/bin/gdef
/usr/bin/gfix
/usr/bin/gpre
/usr/bin/gsec
/usr/bin/isql-fb
/usr/bin/nbackup
/usr/bin/qli
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/firebird
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/fbudf.so
/usr/lib/firebird/2.5/UDF/ib_udf.so
/usr/sbin
/usr/sbin/fb_lock_print
/usr/sbin/fbserver
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/lintian
/usr/share/lintian/overrides
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/firebird2.5-super
/usr/share/man
/usr/share/man/man1
/usr/share/man/man1/fbserver.1.gz
/usr/share/doc/firebird2.5-super
```

UPD 1:

```
dpkg -L firebird-dev
dpkg-query: предупреждение: список файлов пакета «firebird-dev» отсутствует; предполагаем, что на данный момент у пакета нет установленных файлов
Пакет «firebird-dev» не содержит файлов (!)
alexandr@aspire:~$ sudo apt-get install firebird-dev
[sudo] пароль для alexandr: 
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Уже установлен пакет firebird-dev самой новой версии (2.5.6.27020.ds4-2).
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 14 пакетов не обновлено.
не установлено до конца или удалено 15 пакетов.
После данной операции, объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 0 B.
Хотите продолжить? [Д/н] y
```

Comment: Заголовки находятся в dev-пакете: `dpkg -L firebird-dev`.

Comment: @aleks.andr обновил вопрос

Comment: [список файлов пакета](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/firebird-dev): нажмите `list of files` напротив вашей архитектуры.

Comment: @aleks.andr спасибо за список пакетов скачал переустановил.